# Multiprocessing in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration service which needs to read hundreds of XML files from an S3 bucket and process each of them and produce an output. I am using a `S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` along with a custom implementation of the `AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer`.

```
@Bean(name = "s3FileSource")
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "s3Channel" , poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "3000"))
public S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource() {
    S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource messageSource =
            new S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(s3InboundFileSynchronizer());
    messageSource.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    messageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File(inboundDir));
    messageSource.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public CustomAbstractInboundFileSynchronizer s3InboundFileSynchronizer() {

    CustomAbstractInboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer = new CustomAbstractInboundFileSynchronizer(new S3SessionFactory(amazonS3));
    synchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
    synchronizer.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
    synchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(s3BucketName.concat("/").concat(s3InboundFolder));
    synchronizer.setFilter(new S3RegexPatternFileListFilter(".*\\.xml\\.{0,1}\\d{0,2}"));
    Expression expression = PARSER.parseExpression("#this.contains('/') ? #this.substring(#this.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) : #this");
    synchronizer.setLocalFilenameGeneratorExpression(expression);
    return synchronizer;
}
@Bean
public DirectChannel s3Channel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

I want these messages to be processed simultaneously rather than one at a time. The integration flow after this adapter is the same for all the messages.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundSubFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("s3Channel")
            .split()
            .transform(transformer)
            .channel(requestChannel())
            .get();
}
```

I tried using a Splitter `split()` but that doesn't seem to help.
I also tried using a `ThreadPooltaskExecutor` but whenever i use it, i intermittently keep getting error messages saying the `S3 key is invalid` and it leaves the files in the inbound directory with a `.writing` extension.

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: 5A96A2596B6504D6), S3 Extended Request ID: a757llOA1GbivlaRu1Pf41Sz8XLL52WrgbWCa1PnAzanhyEMCwwR3Zx1H/uytjrEJsrh0Yj8M80=
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1378)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:924)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:702)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:454)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:416)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:365)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3995)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1291)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1166)
at org.springframework.integration.aws.support.S3Session.read(S3Session.java:153)
at com.application.service.sample.CustomAbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.copyFileToLocalDirectory(CustomAbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:124)
```

One more thing, each xml file is moved to a different "folder" in S3 after processing.
How do i get to simultaneously process multiple xml files without any errors?

Adding `CustomAbstractInboundFileSynchronizer`:

```
    @Override
protected void copyFileToLocalDirectory(String remoteDirectoryPath, S3ObjectSummary remoteFile, File localDirectory,
                                        Session<S3ObjectSummary> session) throws IOException {
    String remoteFileName = this.getFilename(remoteFile);
    //String localFileName = this.generateLocalFileName(remoteFileName);
    String localFileName = remoteFileName;
    String remoteFilePath = remoteDirectoryPath != null
            ? (remoteDirectoryPath + remoteFileName)
            : remoteFileName;
    if (!this.isFile(remoteFile)) {
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug("cannot copy, not a file: " + remoteFilePath);
        }
        return;
    }

    File localFile = new File(localDirectory, localFileName);
    if (!localFile.exists()) {
        String tempFileName = localFile.getAbsolutePath() + this.temporaryFileSuffix;
        File tempFile = new File(tempFileName);
        OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile));
        try {
            session.read(remoteFilePath, outputStream);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
                throw (RuntimeException) e;
            }
            else {
                throw new MessagingException("Failure occurred while copying from remote to local directory", e);
            }
        }
        finally {
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ignored2) {
            }
        }

        if (tempFile.renameTo(localFile)) {
            if (this.deleteRemoteFiles) {
                session.remove(remoteFilePath);
                if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    this.logger.debug("deleted " + remoteFilePath);
                }
            }
        }
        if (this.preserveTimestamp) {
            localFile.setLastModified(getModified(remoteFile));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing a lot of non-related things and asking too much questions in one thread.

Comment: How about to explain us the reason on that `CustomAbstractInboundFileSynchronizer`, please?

Comment: Why do you need that `s3Channel` as a `QueueChannel`?

Comment: The `@InboundChannelAdapter` produces 1 message per task, indeed. You can modify `@Poller`'s `maxMessagesPerPoll` for your purpose.

Comment: The `.writing` suffix is about local temporary files and indeed it happens before connecting to AWS S3.

Comment: The `S3 key is invalid` is not related to Spring Integration at all. You need to consult your AWS account and S3 bucket for the proper key to use.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I'll try to answer all the Qs here. The reason for the `CustomAbstractInboundFileSynchronizer` is to make sure the files get read from S3 in the correct fashion. The only method added in this class is the `copyFileToLocalDirectory` to read and copy files from S3 to the local dir in the right format. I don't need the channel to be a `QueueChannel`. I can modify it to a `DirectChannel`.

Comment: The `S3 key is invalid` error shows up for a file which was already picked and processed. But looks like somehow the `Synchronizer` is messing up and maybe trying to pick the same file again. The S3 keys and bucket policies are all correct.

Comment: The out of the box `S3InboundFileSynchronizer` has a logic like `((S3Session) session).normalizeBucketName(remoteDirectoryPath)`. I don't see that you use it.

Comment: I don't see any format-specific logic in your code. Why do you care about that format here, on the InboundChannelAdapter? Why just not implement it a bit downstream ?

Comment: Well, for parallel processing you should consider to make that `s3Channel` as `ExecutorChannel`.

Comment: The `.split()` is useless here: `File` object is not collection-like. If you really would like to split lines in the files, you should consider to use `.split(Files.splitter())`

Comment: @ArtemBilan This is what i was referring to and the reason for overriding the method `copyFileToLocalDirectory`: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460074/issues-implementing-spring-integration-aws/44612972#44612972)

Comment: Why just don't use the latest versions of the mentioned Frameworks? Those workarounds were for bugs, but now all of them are fixed. Or am I missing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

To process message in parallel, the [`ExecutorChannel`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-executorchannel) has to be used.

To split file content, line by line, the `.split(Files.splitter())` has to be used. See its JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * The {@link AbstractMessageSplitter} implementation to split the {@link File} Message
 * payload to lines.
 * <p>
 * With {@code iterator = true} (defaults to {@code true}) this class produces an
 * {@link Iterator} to process file lines on demand from {@link Iterator#next}. Otherwise
 * a {@link List} of all lines is returned to the to further
 * {@link AbstractMessageSplitter#handleRequestMessage} process.
 * <p>
 * Can accept {@link String} as file path, {@link File}, {@link Reader} or
 * {@link InputStream} as payload type. All other types are ignored and returned to the
 * {@link AbstractMessageSplitter} as is.
 * <p>
 * If {@link #setFirstLineAsHeader(String)} is specified, the first line of the content is
 * treated as a header and carried as a header with the provided name in the messages
 * emitted for the remaining lines. In this case, if markers are enabled, the line count
 * in the END marker does not include the header line and, if
 * {@link #setApplySequence(boolean) applySequence} is true, the header is not included in
 * the sequence.
 *
 * @author Artem Bilan
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @author Ruslan Stelmachenko
 *
 * @since 4.1.2
 */
public class FileSplitter extends AbstractMessageSplitter {
```

All other your concerns deserves separate SO questions. 
It's hard here on SO take a discussion, plus we really have a limit with comments as well as answer content size.